# Как сделать, чтобы IDEA подсвечивала java-код в jsp файле?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jsp, синтаксис

Начинаю изучать Java и пробую писать веб сервис.
Как настроить IDEA так чтобы в JSP-файле подсвечивался синтаксис Java?

[image: Сейчас в IDEA файл выглядит так]

[image: Нужно что бы выглядело вот так]

Comment: Если это обычный файл то это нельзя сделать. Возможно что нарушена структура проекта, поэтому надо пересоздать ПП проект.

Comment: Пока не понимаю что значит обычный файл. Я зашел в IDEA нажал создать новый проект, выбрал Maven-webapp и все. Я так понял что не настроена какая то ассоциация jsp с java

Comment: Обычный файл - это обычный файл, что тут непонятного? Вопрос вообще не понял. Распиши полнлстью.